# run a page with and without parameter: django

Tags: django, django-urls

i'm working with django. i want a page to work with parameter and without it. i tried using '*' in url like this and it didn't work:

```
url(r'^ask/(?P<pageNo>\d*)/$',
        'ask'),
```

so i think i have to write two urls for my page, one with parameter and the other without it, like this:

```
url(r'^ask/$',
        'ask'),

url(r'^ask/(?P<id>\d+)/$',
        'ask'),
```

it works with parameter, but without it, doesn't work. would you mind please helping me? thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you will have to define 2 urls.

Define your view which takes parameter with default value.

```
def ask(request, id=None):
   ...
   # when id is not passed from url try to get it from GET parameters
   if not id:
      id = request.GET.get('id')
   ...
```